# Data Entities > Domain Objects > ViewModels, each with drastically different data structures

Tags: c#, entity-framework, architecture, domain-driven-design, automapper

This is sort of a generic question in regards to mapping between data entities, domain objects, and ViewModels. I may not be asking it right but hopefully I can make some sense of it. Below is a simplified problem.

Pretend I have an Entity Framework model which maps 1:1 to my database tables, but my domain objects may not be identical, and my ViewModel is drastically different again. As a pseudo-example:

Database/EF Entities:

- MembershipAccount
- MembershipAccountExtraInfo

Domain:

- Account
- Profile
- Preferences

ViewModel:

- UserProfileModel

Let's say I need to display a UserProfileModel which has: Username (*from MembershipAccount*), SignupDate (*from MembershipAccount*), FullName (*from MembershipAccountExtraInfo*), and TimeZone (*from MembershipAccountExtraInfo*)

What sort of relationships might I need here, and what sort of mapping mechanisms? Is it common to have something like an AccountMapper that takes both a MembershipAccount and MembershipAccountExtraInfo and returns an Account? I'm a bit stuck on the mapping when several objects are needed to create a single domain entity, and vice versa.

If it helps: I'm designing an API for managing User Accounts, User Profiles, User Preferences, etc. but the database tables are all over the place. A single User Profile might need to be created from data spanning 4-5 tables and 2 databases. There is no 1:1 mapping between my database tables and any (logical) domain objects.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to map multiple OBJECTS to one object using AutoMapper - asp.net mvc 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580392/how-to-map-multiple-objects-to-one-object-using-automapper-asp-net-mvc-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to work keeping my domain objects as close to the objects that they represent as possible. What I mean by this is that if an account has preferences, then the domain `Account` object should contain a `Preferences` property, most likely represented by a collection of `Preference` objects. If nothing else, this helps the users understand the data structure of the application easily.

As for constructing the view models, that's the easiest bit... you add just properties for anything that is required. What types of properties you would need would really depend on how you have structured your domain objects.

If your view has the requirements that you mentioned in your question and you modelled your domain objects closely on the objects that they represent, then by the sounds of it, you would just need an `Account` object because that would contain the `Preference` and `Profile` objects inside it.

Finally, the only 'mapping' that needs to be done can be done with a `LinQ` query using the Entity Framework. It is at this point that I join the tables and pull whatever data that I need for whichever object I am working on. Here is an example of instantiating objects from data from three tables (using `LinQ2SQL`):

```
public AudioTracks GetAudioTracks(AudioTrackSearchOptions searchOptions)
{
    AudioTracks audioTracks;
    using (MidasDataContext dataContext = DataContext)
    {
        audioTracks = new AudioTracks(
            from audioTrack in dataContext.DbAudioTracks
            join masterTrack in dataContext.DbMasterTracks on audioTrack.MasterTrackId equals masterTrack.Id
            join masterTrackArtist in dataContext.DbDataLists on masterTrack.ArtistId equals masterTrackArtist.Id
            orderby string.Concat(masterTrack.Title, " (", audioTrack.Mix, ") - ", masterTrackArtist.Text)
            where (searchOptions.IsInactiveAudioTrackIncluded || audioTrack.IsActive)
            && (searchOptions.IsDeletedAudioTrackIncluded || !audioTrack.IsDeleted)
            select new AudioTrack(audioTrack.Id, masterTrack.Id, audioTrack.Isrc, masterTrack.Title, masterTrackArtist.Text, audioTrack.Mix, audioTrack.IsContentExplicit, audioTrack.IsActive, audioTrack.IsDeleted));
    }
    audioTracks.Sort(a => a.TitleWithMix);
    return audioTracks ?? new AudioTracks();
}
```

---

UPDATE >>>

Extending my `AudioTracks` example and working backwards, the `GetAudioTracks` method is in a project called `DataProviders`. It is called from a `GetAudioTracks` method in a `DataController` class which just adds user feedback and re-try options. That in turn is called by a `TracksModel` in the `Models` project which just contains a subsection of methods from the `DataController` class that relate to the various types of tracks in the application.

Finally, the `AudioTracksViewModel` in the `ViewModels` project calls the `TracksModel.GetAudioTracks` method upon initialisation which happens when the `AudioTracksView` is loaded by the user. The `AudioTracksView` has a `ListBox` on the left containing all of the `AudioTrack` objects that meet the users search and/or filter selections. The right of the screen has the fields for the selected `AudioTrack`. Here is what it looks like (if the link seems broken, you can view the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjQcq.png)):

[image: AudioTracksView]

The more transparent fields with an edit `Button` on the right are read only fields connected to collections. The edit `Button` opens a dialog to let the user enter multiple items, which are then summarised in the field. All of the objects in the application have similar views of more or less complexity.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'll definitely mull over this a bit. I guess what I've been missing out on (or so it seems) is that a composition pattern within the domain layer is probably going to solve a lot of my problems (e.g. - Account object with a Preferences and Profile object inside of it). I realize this is a very domain-specific problem but your suggestion is very helpful!

Comment: Glad I could help. Let me know if you have any follow up questions.

Comment: I'm curious, if my domain objects should model my real-world objects (makes sense to me, since this is the "business layer") then the example you give above is in your Repository I assume? So the GetAudioTracks() is a Repository method that presumably returns an AudioTracks collection (domain object) to a service layer or another business layer function? Your example is very clear but would you be willing to provide a bit more context on the GetAudioTracks() method, where it exists and what calls it? Thank you so much!

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you for so much detail! So if I understand correctly, the DataProviders project is a repository essentially (I guess it would be in this case, or maybe it's more akin to a DAL)? I'm really not trying to shoehorn your example into a design pattern, just my way of understanding the layering you have. :)

Either way, your example is clear and informative and I'll gladly mark it as answer since it really has helped me figure some things out. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, I would call the `DataProviders` project more of a data access layer than a repository, although in reality, there's not too much difference. I'm glad the example helped.